# PHP Extension development ubuntu

Tags: php, php-extension

I created an extension based on some tutorials and began to develop extension using eclipse IDE with PHP source.

I compiled the extension independently using phpize not compiled with whole PHP.  Now I have the .so file then I moved it to the /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs directory and updated php.ini file, these locations are for already installed php. not from the source where I compiled the extension. (installed PHP and PHP source both are same version PHP 5.3.10 so that i can run the extension on already installed locations)

here is my question,
How do i test my extension using the same php source which i used in eclipse. I don't want to install the PHP that resides in eclipse work space again but how do we specify the php.ini and load extensions in compiled php source itself?

Comment: compule the extension on the server with the same version of php + sources + headers as the server uses otherwise you've got to cross compile which adds a level of complexity

Comment: I compiled the extension from PHP source that's in my local system and moved the ".so" files to the server. its working fine because both are same versions.

but i cant run the same inside my php source until I moved it to the 
installed php on the server. why?

i can run using PHP CLI but how do i map php.ini and .so file locations in PHP source itself for testing purpose?

Comment: extensions are modular you shouldn't need to touch the php source at all just create the .so (library) then tell the php.ini to load it and you're away as long as your .so exposes classes/methods/hooks etc to the php runtime its self which it should do as you extend the php source in your extension

Comment: yeah... you are right. 
when i run the php cli from the untared compiled php source how do we specify the php.ini if we didn't installed the same.
can we specify its path while configure php?
php --ini shows no php.ini loaded :(

Comment: its set as an environment variable when you install php on both windows and linux you cannot really use php from just untared and compiled source without running make install after to move the binarys into the correct location and setup the ini location and environment vars.

Comment: After compiling the source we can run the php via cli in the source its self without make install. 
i need to just test the extension rather running on a server. is it possible?

Comment: if you mean run it through apache you need to make sure you compile mod_php for apache not just the apache bin from the raw source, you then need to make sure that mod apache is installed loaded into apache at run time and restart apache